# subfolders in Content folder returning 404 Not Found when published to Azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I have the following folder structure:

```
Content
Content/full-calendar/*.css
Content/font-awesome/css/*.css
Content/font-awesome/webfonts/*.*
```

Now when I debug my MVC site all is good. However when I publish the site to Azure cloud app service, the page doesn't render correctly. From Chrome developer's tool I can see the bundle has been replaced by this:

```
https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/Content/fullcalendar/?v=Qe_Y_dvAGv4t20VtvwjdqpV3S6aiAa0SQmXfX4u8NcI1
```

which returns 404 Not found. I am confident it is something to do with creating the subfolder in Content. Note that the contents of the subfolders are all Content / Do not copy.

How can I fix this?

I have this in BundleConfig.cs

```
        // full calendar
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fullcalendar").Include(
            "~/Content/full-calendar/main.min.css"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fullcalendar").Include(
            "~/Scripts/full-calendar/main.min.js"));

        // font awesome
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesome").Include(
            "~/Content/font-awesome/css/all.min.css"));
```

Also this is what I have in my _layout.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fullcalendar")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendar")
```

Comment: Or alternatively what is the recommended way to organize css and js files from components in the MVC project? I was trying to avoid putting all css in Content folder and js in Script folder so that in future it makes maintaining difficult

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: Has your problem been solved and is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

> Content/full-calendar/*.css
>
> @Styles.Render("~/Content/**fullcalendar**")

> Content/font-awesome/css/*.css
>
> @Styles.Render("~/Content/**fontawesome**")

Your folder name is missing a `-` symbol.

[image]

I think this problem not only occurs on `azure`, but also occurs when you are debugging locally. Please refer to my screenshot to modify it. I hope it can help you. After local debugging is passed, there will be no problems after release.